# NSUserDefault getting reset

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, macos

I have an OSX app, where I'm using NSUserDefault to store simple value and a lot of people have started reporting to me, that the values in NSUserDefault is getting deleted randomly.

Has anyone else experienced something similar? I've searched all over SO, but I don't seem to find anyone else with the same issue.

Comment: Is it OSX or iOS - please remove the incorrect tags.  Also you need to show some code otherwise we have no idea.  Given how widespread use of NSUserDefaults is it is highly unlikely to be a problem with iOS - you are removing or resetting the values somewhere

Answer (score 1):

`NSUserDefaults` can be vanished, when you change your `BundleIdentifier`,
as the file is stored by your bundleId.

They can be found in more than one place:

```
~/Library/Preferences/com.example.myapp.plist
~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.example.myapp.plist
```

and if sandboxed

```
~/Library/Containers/com.example.myapp/Data/Library/Preferences/com.example.myapp.plist
~/Library/Containers/com.example.myapp/Data/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.example.myapp.plist
```

Comment: If you change the app's bundle ID, it also shows up as a separate app. You can't change the bundle ID once you've created the app on iTunesConnect. You can't even submit it to the App Store unless the bundle ID matches.

Comment: That's what's confusing me, because I'm not changing the bundle ID in any way (and of course I can't if I wanted to), but still the NSUserDefaults seems to be getting reset for a lot of people. Could there be any other reason for this? My app is sandboxed btw.

Comment: You can check if you're calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` after setObject calls.

Comment: I am calling synchronise as well, after setting the data. So I'm pretty sure it's not that. Any other suggestions?